Displaying Raspberry PI Camera 3 using PyQt5 on Pi5 Results in Odd Images
I am trying to use PyQt5 to continuously display a Raspberry Pi Camera Module 3. When I display the image taken from the camera as a QImage it shows up in a format that you can see the sensor doing things but the display is just blown out pixels. The code I am using is attached.
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QLabel, QVBoxLayout, QWidget
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap, QImage
import PIL.ImageTk
import picamera2

class CameraWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(CameraWidget, self).__init__(parent)

        self.camera = picamera2.Picamera2()
        self.camera.sensor_mode = 2  # Choose sensor mode 2 for 640x480 resolution
        self.camera.configure(self.camera.create_preview_configuration(main={"size": (640, 480)}))
        self.camera.start()

        self.label = QLabel()
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.timer = QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.update_frame)
        self.timer.start(int(1000 / 24))

    def update_frame(self):
        image = self.camera.capture_array()
        qt_image = QImage(image.data, 640, 480, QImage.Format_RGB16)
        # qt_image = ImageQt(image).convertToQImage()
        pixmap = QPixmap.fromImage(qt_image)
        self.label.setPixmap(pixmap)

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle("Raspberry Pi Camera Viewer")
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 640, 480)

        self.central_widget = CameraWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.central_widget)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


I tried editing the QImage.format to different formats and it did not fix the issue.

Are you sure that the image format is correct? Also, try the QImage constructor that accepts the bytesPerLine argument and use it accordingly.

I'm assuming image is a numpy array?  If so, what tuple values does image.shape return?

@G.M. Yes it is a numpy array. It is in the shape (640, 480, 4). I have actually found a fix using the PIL images the camera can generate. I will post an answer to this on the fix.

The fix was to not use the numpy arrays from PiCamera2.capture_array() and rather use the PIL images from PiCamera2.capture_image(). Here is an updated CameraWidget.update_frame():
def update_frame(self):
    image = self.camera.capture_image()
    image = image.convert("RGBA")
    data = image.tobytes("raw", "RGBA")
    qim = ImageQt(image)
    pix = PyQt5.QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(qim)
    self.label.setPixmap(pix)

